# How to create a proxy server for iFrames in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a web proxy for my iFrame to get around CORS. I would like to be able to access any website using my iFrame. At the moment I am making a request to my server with the URL I would like to access. My server is making a GET request to this URL and I am getting a string with all the HTML data in the response.data body of the response. The iFrame won't accept this HTML string response, so I am not sure what to do next. I would have to parse the html, css and js but I don't know how.

React Code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Browser() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const [htmlValue, setHtmlvalue] = useState('');

    function handleInputChange(e) {
        setValue(e.target.value);
    }

    async function handleKeyPress() {
        const { data: html } = await getUrlHtml();
        setHtmlvalue(html);
    }

    async function getUrlHtml() {
        const body = {
            url: value,
        };
        const html = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000', body);
        return html;
    }

    return (
        <Container>
            <input
                type="text"
                value={value}
                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                onKeyPress={(e) => e.key === 'Enter' && handleKeyPress()}
            />
            <iframe width="600" height="450" src={htmlValue} title="WebHub-Browser"></iframe>
        </Container>
    );
}

const Container = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px;
`;
```

Node.js Code (Routes function is doing the GET request at the moment):

```
import express, {Request, Response} from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import http from 'http';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import axios from 'axios';

class App {
    private app: express.Application;
    private server: any;
    private port: number;

    public constructor(port: number) {
        this.app = express();
        this.port = port;
        this.middlewares();
        this.routes();
        this.createServer();
    }

    private middlewares(): void {
        this.app.use(express.json());
        this.app.use(cors());
        this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: 1.5 * 1024 * 1024 }));
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: 1.5 * 1024 * 1024 }));
    }

    private createServer(): void {
        this.server = new http.Server(this.app);
    }

    private routes(): void {
        this.app.post('/', async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<express.Response> => {
            const { url } = req.body;
            const response = await axios.get(url);

            return res.send(response.data);
        });
    }

    public listen(): void {
        this.server.listen(this.port, () => {
            console.log(`App running on port ${this.port}`);
        });
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: An iframe takes an url as its `src`, not a html string. You don't need axios on the client side. Just make a GET route like `http://localhost:5000/proxy?url=…` and use that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bergi, some weird behaviors are going on though. Youtube loaded once properly and it never did again. Stackoverflow loaded properly and then it started to redirect me to the stackoverflow website for some reason instead of opening it inside my iFrame. I also would need to solve the issue of retrieve nested urls, like if for example you click on a video on youtube. Any ideas?

Comment: No. Most pages don't like being loaded into iframes for security reasons, and having interactivity (allow to run scripts) would amount to completely virtualising a browser.

Comment: @Windbox, Did you succeed with this problem?

Comment: @EugeneW. No, I didn't. If I remember correctly, I was trying to create a dashboard where the user would be able to open multiple websites within it. In order to get that working without the limitations of iFrames I would have to either virtualize a browser in the server (like a headless Chromes for example) and stream the data back to my dashboard. Another solution would be to create an extension instead of a regular website, but at the time I deemed these solutions way too complex to implement or not good enough for me and I ditched the idea entirely.

Comment: @Windbox, I understand. iframes are really isolated very well.